# Facebook group's sole administrator deleted her account

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I am a member of a fairly active Facebook group. We had one administrator, but she deleted her account or something and now there are no admins. However, Facebook still thinks there is one admin. Looking at the members page, it shows in the navigation bar "Admins (1)" but when clicked on to show the admins, it says "No admins" or whatever.

The "add myself as an admin" button does not show up, but when I try to add myself that way anyway it gives an error (presumably because Facebook thinks that there already is an admin).

Is there any way for somebody to become an admin of this group?

It has been like this for a few months.

Comment: Are you sure she deleted her account and just not blocked you? The 1 indicates that. I was in a group where the owner deleted her account and I just hijacked the group then. Very simple and immoral.

Answer (score -1):

There can be more than one admin to a group, but you have to be a admin to add an admin and or the creator of the group. If you are just a member it will not let you add yourself as admin. It will always show one admin as the creator is an admin but might not show you who that person is or it could be one in the same as the person who left facebook.